# nginx url prameter rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

We are migrating forum software and want to preserve our link equity. I am trying to rewrite urls in nginx from

```
/forum/read.php?1,171967,171967#msg-171967
```

to

```
/forum/discussion/171967
```

It doesn't matter which of the 171967 strings it matches. I've tried:

```
rewrite ^/forum/read.php(.*),([0-9]+),(.*)$ /forum/discussion/$2 redirect;
```

and several other variations to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message number you are attempting to capture is part of the query string and not therefore not part of the *normalised URI* used by the `rewrite` and `location` directives. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

If `/forum/read.php` is not a valid URI in the new forum software, you can use an exact match `location` to isolate it.

The easiest way to run a *regular expression* over the query string, is with an `if` block.

For example:

```
location = /forum/read.php {
    if ($args ~ ,([0-9]+),) {
        return 301 /forum/discussion/$1;
    }
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.